# Make Authentication needed for a controller in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I have a controller named Test. I have used spring-security-core-2.0-RC2 plugin and my grails version is 2.1.1. I have put this at my config file >>

```
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/Test/**':                       ['permitAll']
]
```

I need that only logged in users can access Test controller. But here every user can access it. Is there any way to do it ? Can anybody please help me on this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in '`IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`' to indicate that the user must be fully authenticated to access the URI.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/Test/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```